# switch components in react js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, components

I'm doing a singlepage application and would like to switch a component.

Here is an image how it looks like:

[image]

If I click on the button in component 3, I will switch the component 3 with 5.
So maybe like component 3 is a view of all projects and if I click on one project, I will see a detail view of the project with some information.
I created two different components for this.
All other components should stay at the same place.

Here is my code how I switch the components:

```
  this.state.detailVisible
      ? <ProjectDetailView/>
    : null
```

I'm not sure if is the correct react way to do it. Also I have two different css files for component 3 and 5. If I'm switching the two component, I have some class name irritations with my css.

If it's a better way to do it with routers?
How is the react way to do it?

thanks for your help :)

Comment: [Conditional rendering](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html) should be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on your needs, if you need to render both `component3` and `component5` then a route won't be much of a help.
If you need to render only one of them then a route can be handy.
as for the syntax i prefer this:
`this.state.detailVisible && <ProjectDetailView/>`

here is a simple example:

```js
const components = ["Component1", "Component2", "Component3"];

class Component extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      showDetails: false
    };

    this.onComponentClicked = this.onComponentClicked.bind(this);
  }
  onComponentClicked(e) {
    this.setState({
      showDetails: !this.state.showDetails
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { name } = this.props;
    const { showDetails } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <div>Component{name}</div>
        <button onClick={this.onComponentClicked}>Toggle Details</button>
        {showDetails && <ComponentDetails name={name} />}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const ComponentDetails = ({ name }) => (
  <div>
    <div>Details of component{name}</div>
  </div>
);

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Parent</h2>
        {components.map(c => {
          return (
            <div>
              <Component name={c} />
              <hr />
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: thanks. yeah I just want to parse my data in the components and display the results. but why I have the issue with my css?

Comment: @Stan I've added a simple example

Comment: As for css scope you can and should work with css modules or styled components libs